# select menu inside a div with fixed position on mobile safari, iphone

Tags: iphone, select, fixed

I am building a site that has a header with a fixed position which contains a select menu.  The header is supposed to stay locked to the top of the screen due to the position:fixed in css.  However, when clicking the select menu in mobile safari on iphone, the header no longer stays locked to the top when the ios select menu opens.  It seems that ios is centering the div with the select menu onto the visible area of the screen above the menu.  This doesn't happen when the page is scrolled to the top, but when the address bar is not visible, it "breaks" like so.  Haven't found any other answers, maybe I'm asking the question the wrong way.  I can't post links to code yet, any help is appreciated.

http://selfconstruc.tv/menu-open.PNG
http://selfconstruc.tv/menu-closed.PNG

Comment: There is a lot of articles related to the issues with `position:fixed` on IOS. In IOS 5.1.1 or earlier it just didn't work. In more recent versions it works but has some issues. See this [Issues with position fixed & scrolling on iOS](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/)

Comment: thanks nmoliveira.  focus jumping describes exactly what i am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For now I don't think there is a perfect solution to deal with the focus jumping.
In my case I hide the header on focus in and show again in focus out and it works well.
I don't know if in your case this could be a workaround.

You can try this:

```
// detect ios device
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/gi)){
  // hide header on focus in and show on focus out
  jQuery("#content").focusin(function(){
    jQuery('#your-header-id').hide();
  })
  jQuery("#content").focusout(function(){
    jQuery('your-header-id').show();
  })
}
```

The #content is a div where you should have all your controls, the jQuery .focusin() detects the focus event on parent elements, so every control will trigger the focus event. You hide the header on focus and show after that. Hope this helps!